# Running a Flask App under Apache with Plesk

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualhost, plesk

Having no end of problems running Flask under Apache using Plesk. Really been scratching my head with this one.

As I am using Plesk, I realise that I need to use the **vhosts** conf files under /var/www/vhosts instead of the virtualhost config (sitting under the typical "sites-available" directory in Apache).

When I attempt to run my Flask App, I receive the error within my Apache error log:

> Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'unifica': /apps/start.wsgi

My wsgi application file lives here:

> /apps/start.wsgi

and reads as follows:

```
activate_this = '/apps/unifica/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
from unifica import app as application
```

As you will notice. I am using a Virtual Environment. 
Subsequently, my actual application lives here:

> apps/unifica/main.py

and reads as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

As my site is secured over ssl; I have the following two vhost configurations:

> vhost.conf and vhost_ssl.conf

My vhost.conf contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

(to redirect insecure requests)

My vhost_ssl.conf contains:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess unifica user=flaskuser group=flaskgroup threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /apps/start.wsgi

<Directory /apps >
    WSGIProcessGroup unifica
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
    WSGIScriptReloading On
</Directory>
```

flaskuser exists and belongs to flaskgroup. I have assigned 0755 rights to flaskuser (as the owner) on the /apps/ folder.

Any idea where I am going wrong here? I presume I have made a fairly obvious mistake somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not resolved this yet I was able to get Flask working by editing the custom vhost file in Plesk 12.5 this is on CentOS7. It's located here;

/var/www/vhosts/system/{domain}/conf/vhost.conf

Example of what was added;

`<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName example.com
                ServerAdmin me@example.com
                WSGIScriptAlias /var/www/vhost/{domain}/{subdomain}/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/vhost/{domain}/{subdomain}/static>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/vhost/{domain}/{subdomain}/static
                <Directory /var/www/vhost/{domain}/{subdomain}/static>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

On my setup I am using permissions 705. Keep in mind some of these edits are made for a subdomain. I hope you get your issue resolved!

Comment: Hi Dave,

Thanks for the response. We ended up scrapping Plesk as it was causing more administrative difficulties than it was solving. 

Thanks!